# How to correctly resolve the git permission denied error

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I'm confused about the git.

I think I tried to change git settings to get into another account, but it's gone bad now. i can't pump out my public repository because:
`git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).`
I cleaned .ssh but and reinstalled git with brew, but that didn't work. I also tried this
`ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` but that didn't help either.
`ssh -vT git@github.com` got this result:

```
OpenSSH_9.4p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-57ca1323
debug1: compat_banner: no match: babeld-57ca1323
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/ckaf/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/ckaf/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/ckaf/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/ckaf/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

As far as I can tell all my git configs are empty, so I can't figure out what the problem is, I seem to have overmodded the keys. I also tried gh auth login via https and I was able to login but git gives the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+Permission+denied+publickey

Comment: `ssh-keyscan` is Ok, what about `ssh-keygen`?